# how to set variables in tcl

Tags: variables, tcl

I saw someone set a variable in this way:

```
set selectRoom(1,deflt) 1
```

what does this `selectRoom(1,deflt)`means? how this works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`selectRoom` is an array and `1,deflt` is the index.
To see what is set in the array, you can use `parray` or `array get` command.

Comment: but what is the index of this array? these is only one element in this array and "1,deflt" is the index?

Comment: The index is just any text sequence between '(' and ')'.

Comment: The index is “`1,deflt`”. It's an associative array that's indexed by string key. C-like numeric-indexed arrays are mapped to Tcl lists (and they're formally values).

Answer (score 1):

As was said before, `selectRoom` is an array, but I would just like to expand on that answer.

You might be tempted to think that the index `1,deflt` suggests that this is a 2 dimensional array. In fact it isn't; [Tcl does not support multidimensional arrays](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1032). The comma notation is just a convention that Tcl programmers use to simulate multidimensional arrays. The comma is part of the string, not andy kind of special delimiter.

In Tcl, arrays are a bit like hash maps in other languages. The index is always a string (because [everything is a string in Tcl](http://wiki.tcl.tk/3018)). This has another implication: they are not ordered, so you have to be careful when you are iterating over them.